# How to populate a 2D array with Strings (char*) from a CSV file in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, csv

I am working on a project where I am trying to read in a CSV file and check it for all sorts of different parameters.  C is a new language for me so I am still getting used to it, and my code may not be as streamlined as it could be.  Anyways, my issue is this: when I read the file to make sure each row has the same number of entries it works fine, but when I try to put the values into a 2D array everything gets messed up.  The value at arr[0][0] should be the first value in the CSV file, but when I print out to see what it is, it is always the first value in the last row.  I can't for the life of me figure this out, and I have been looking at this code and tinkering with it for hours.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
int parseFile(int width, int height, char*fileName) {

char*** matrix = malloc(width*height*sizeof(char*));
int counter = 0;
int pointer = 0;
FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
const size_t line_size = 1024;
char* line = (char*) malloc(line_size);

while (fgets(line, line_size, file) != NULL) {
    char** data = malloc(width*sizeof(char*));
    char *delim = ",";
    char *string = strtok(line, delim);
    while (string != NULL) {
       size_t ln = strlen(string) - 1;
        if (string[ln] == '\n') {
            string[ln] = '\0';
        }
        data[counter] = string;

        string = strtok(NULL, delim);
        counter++;
    }
    matrix[pointer] = data;
   counter = 0;
   pointer++;
}
printf("%s", matrix[0][0]);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `char*** matrix = malloc(width*height*sizeof(char));`...smells foul.

Comment: what do you mean by that? even when I stored all the strings in a single array, it overrode the first entry onward every time there was a new line.

Comment: whoops, that was originally printf("%s", matrix[0][0]); but I was doing some tests and forgot to change it back.  I edited the code above to have the right print statement.

Comment: `data[counter] = string;` : `string` point to part of `line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks nearly right, but what is happening is `strtok` is returning a pointer into line.  That means it only has copies of the last line.

Consider creating a new memory slot for each line, or `strdup` the result from `strtok`